# JS: Selecting div's href's and applying the text of href to an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` named #div1 which gets a random values of `href`.
For example:

```
<div>
<a href="#"> Apple </a>
<a href="#"> Orange </a>
<a href="#"> Lemon </a>
<a href="#"> Banana </a>
</div>
```

How is it possible, when ever I click any of those to be applied to `input` #input1 with `Javascript`?

The form is: `<input type="text" name="q" id="input1" >`

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions hints you want the `href` attribute to populate the `input` element.

```
$('#div1 > a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#input1').val($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Mcm2V/).

If you want the whole path by the `href` attribute, use `this.href`.

If it was really the text node you were after, replace `this.href` above with `$.trim($(this).text())`.

Comment: @rallyboy I updated with a fiddle. The problem with your fiddle is `div1 != #div1`.

Comment: thanks alot. My question was if its possible I can get the value of the href. AS like Apple, Orange etc. So when I click Apple I get apple in the input since the names in Div1 are random every time. Thanks alot again

Comment: @rally boy: change `this.href` to `$(this).html()` (for the values banana, lemon etc) or `$(this).href` for the href value

Comment: @rallyboy The text node is not the `href` attribute. See my answer, my last sentence shows how to modify it to get the text node instead.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code to get the value Lemon, Banana etc in the text box....
HTML:

```
<div1>
<a href="#"> Apple </a>
<a href="#"> Orange </a>
<a href="#"> Lemon </a>
<a href="#"> Banana </a>
</div>

    <input type="text" name="q" id="input1" >
```

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        $('div1 > a').click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $('#input1').val($(this).html());
        });

    </script>
```